# Highcharts cloud issue with data source when duplicating chart

Tags: highcharts, google-sheets, duplicates

I'm fairly new to highcharts cloud and am trying to replicate a bunch of charts that are styled the same but have different data connections with Google Sheets. I've created a base chart and then replicated it a bunch of times for the other charts I need using the **DUPLICATE** button, then simply change the Google Sheets ID to a different one.

The trouble is that whenever I update the ID in the newly created chart, it also updates the ID in the chart I duplicated from - and for all other charts that I've duplicated from. So I end up with a bunch of charts that reference to the single sheet rather than individual sheets. Is this something that's known?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me explain what happens when you duplicate a chart. If the master chart contains some data then duplicating a chart does not create new information about that data. This means both charts, master and duplicated, are **linked to the same dataset**. If you change anything in data in master chart, then duplicated charts will inherit those changes too. The same will happen if you make changes in data in the duplicated chart - it will affect master chart.

To use the same colors and formatting across your different charts, please use **Themes**: https://cloud.highcharts.com/docs/#/themes